# Store multiple disconnected datasets in SQL correctly

Tags: sql, database-schema

I have multiple datasets with identical schema and I am not sure how I should design the `SQL` correctly here. The question is very simple, but I just do not have experience with `SQL`. Lets' say that there are 40 tables that store matrix data as `row_num, col_num, val`. Each such table has its own name. Because the tables have hundreds of millions of rows, to fit all of them into just one table seems wrong from the point of performance. So, I am thinking of creating `40` tables, but I am not sure how optimal schema should look like in this case. Each such table, that represents a matrix, in turn, will have the relevant tables with different schema:

```
table_of_type_MATRIX_1 --> table_of_type_BIRDS (relevant for table_of_type_MATRIX_1 only!)
table_of_type_MATRIX_2 --> table_of_type_BIRDS (relevant for table_of_type_MATRIX_2 only!)
```

So, basically there is a bunch of kind of disconnected data that I want to store in one database and I am not sure how to organize it. There will be queries, of course, which will require looking into multiple tables with identical schema. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Example

Matrix looks like that:

```
       gene                      cell_id       expr
0  0610005C13Rik  GCTAAGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC   0.000000
1  0610007N19Rik  GCTAAGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC   0.000000
2  0610007P14Rik  GCTAAGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC   3.593143
3  0610009B22Rik  GCTAAGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC   3.593143
4  0610009D07Rik  GCTAAGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC  10.779429
...
other dozen millions of rows
```

It is the matrix of gene expression: in the first column we have gene that is expressed in the cell that is shown in the second column with the expression level shown in the third. The cells (second column) are also grouped into clusters after dimensionality reduction and clustering algorithms are run, and so, we have second table that is related to the first:

```
  cell_id                     cluster
  GCTAAGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC        1
  GCTGGGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC        2
  GCTAAGTATAAN_CTL-6_OPC        2
  GCTAAGTATTTN_CTL-6_OPC        3
  ...
  and so on for all of the cells
```

So, these two related tables: gene expression matrix and cells' clusters assignment will form a disconnected dataset in itself. There will be many such groups of 2 tables that need to be stored.

Comment: Store them as an xmltype or a Json type if its mssql 2016 or higher

Comment: Do your rows and columns have any particular significance?  SQL databases won't have problems with long tables... but make sure they're *logical* tables.

Comment: I am using SQLite. I mean, it will not have problems if I store several billion rows? I thought that starting from hundreds of millions it gets very slow and so table needs to be split up, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Your description is too vague to answer the questions you ask. If you want to have an idea of alternate designs then give some exact one we can refer to transforming. [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097)

Comment: Ок, will try giving an actual example